Is it possible to get the local formula of Laplacian on Kähler manifolds from local formula on Riemannian manifolds?
From Riemannian:
\begin{align*}
\Delta f&=\frac1{\sqrt G}\frac\partial{\partial x^s}\left(g^{sk}\sqrt G\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\right)\\
&={g^{sk}}_{,s}f_{,k}+\frac1{\sqrt G}g^{sk}f_{,k}\frac{Gg^{ij}g_{ji,s}}{2\sqrt G}+g^{sk}f_{,sk}\\
&=-g^{si}g_{ij,s}g^{jk}f_{,k}+\frac12g^{sk}g^{ij}g_{ji,s}f_{,k}+g^{sk}f_{,sk}\\
&=-g^{si}g_{ij,s}g^{jk}f_{,k}+\frac12g^{jk}g^{si}g_{is,j}f_{,k}+g^{sk}f_{,sk}\\
&=\color{blue}{g^{si}g^{jk}\left(\frac12g_{is,j}-g_{ij,s}\right)f_{,k}}\color{red}{+g^{sk}f_{,sk}},
\end{align*}
where the range of values for all dummy indices is from $1$ to $2n$.

From Kähler:
$$h^{s\bar k}=h(d z^s,d z^k)=h(dx^s+idy^s,dx^k+idy^k)\\=2g(dx^s,dx^k)-2ig(dx^s,dy^k)=2(g^{sk}-ig^{s~k+n}),$$
$$\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial z^s \partial \bar{z}^k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial  \bar{z}^k}\frac12(f_{,s}-if_{,s+n})=\frac14(f_{,sk}+f_{,s+n~k+n})+\frac i4(f_{,s~k+n}-f_{,s+n~k}).$$
where the range of values for all dummy indices is from $1$ to $n$. So
\begin{align*}
\Delta f&=2 h^{s\bar{k}} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial z^s \partial \bar{z}^k}\\
&=(g^{sk}-ig^{s~k+n})((f_{,sk}+f_{,s+n~k+n})+i(f_{,s~k+n}-f_{,s+n~k}))\\
&=\color{red}{g^{sk}(f_{,sk}+f_{,s+n~k+n})+g^{s~k+n}(f_{,s~k+n}-f_{,s+n~k})}\\
&\color{blue}{+ig^{sk}(f_{,s~k+n}-f_{,s+n~k})-ig^{s~k+n}(f_{,sk}+f_{,s+n~k+n})},
\end{align*}

Since the complex structure is compatible with the metric, $g^{sk}=g^{s+n~k+n}$ and $g^{s~k+n}=-g^{s+n~k}$, so the red terms are equal. But it seems difficult to see that the blue terms are equal... I know we can use Kähler identities in Hodge theory to get the formula, but out of curiosity, I also want to know if this way is feasible.

It is! Note that there might be a factor of $2$ depending on your definition of the Laplacian in Kähler geometry. Here is how I would do it: start from the fact that on a Riemannian manifold $\Delta(f)=\div,\nabla(f)$. In local real coordinates this is $\nabla_j\nabla^jf$ and gives you the same formula you had. In complex coordinates instead it writes as $\nabla_j\nabla^jf+\nabla_{\bar{j}}\nabla^{\bar{j}}f$. Each of these two terms is in fact equal to $g^{j\bar{k}}\partial_j\partial_{\bar{k}}f$ using the Kähler property. This might be different from what you had in mind, however...
